# Integration $\int dx f(x,y)$ by replacing $\int dx f(x,\xi)$ for some transcendental number $\xi$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Sometimes when I'm doing a hard integral $\int dx f(x,y)$ where $y$ is a parameter, I replace $y$ with, say, the transcendental number $\zeta(\pi)$, Mathematica will evaluate it more easily, and I'll replace each occurrence of $\zeta(\pi)$ in the final result with $y$. In plenty of instances this procedure works better than integrating with variable $y$ even with additional "Assumptions." Sometimes it is the only way to do the integral I know.

As long as the transcendental number is in the same set (positive reals, negative reals, complex, etc.) as $y$ I don't worry too much about this; sometimes I numerically integrate for some other values to verify the result. Are there some generic situations when this procedure will *not* give me the right result, barring obvious cases (e.g. don't choose $\zeta(2)$ or $\pi$, don't do this when working with the defining integral for some transcendental number, etc.)?

Comment: This is a nice question. I usually use this trick with a number I do not expect to show up in the context of whatever is being evaluated, and `Khinchin` is often my choice for this.

Comment: One potential bad case is when the parameter you replace with a numeric quantity might have invalid values e.g. where a branch cut is encountered. This can be dependent on the integration bounds of course. What is lost in such cases is a conditional result that contains provisos.